# Can not read number send with DataOutputStream

Tags: java, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

this is my Client code

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeInt(n);
```

and this is the Server code

```
try {
     DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));  
     int fromClient = input.read();
     System.out.println(fromClient);
} catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i don't recive anything in fromClient , even if i chnage it like this

```
System.out.println(fromClient+"test");
```

i don't got result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client needs to either call `dos.flush()` or `dos.close()` to cause buffered data to be pushed to the server.  (If you intend to write more data, then flush, otherwise close.)

The server side needs to read the data using readInt on the `DataInputStream` instance.  Data that is written using a DataOutputStream should be read using a DataInputStream.

Finally, get rid of BufferedReader/InputStreamReader.  It is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `writeInt()` on the write side, you should be using `readInt()` on the read side (all the method names correlate between DataOutputStream and DataInputStream, please read the javadoc).